# Is it okay to connect a PureComponent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-component

I was wondering if this is okay:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ListItem extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>Some Text</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(ListItem);
```

And than maybe add `mapStateToProps()`. Or is this an Anti-pattern? I've heard that PureComponents can slow down performance...

Comment: why you want to do something like that? what is your motivate? it sees you dont use anything from state reducers..

Comment: PureComponents can slow down performance - where did you hear?

Comment: IMO if it's purely a UI component that can be re-used across your application with varying data, I'd pass props through to ListItem and avoid connecting it to Redux.

Comment: @hodcaspi I didn't do it yet. I asked the question in the middle of writing the ListItem, wondering if it was okay what I was about todo. Therefore `mapStateToProps()` is not implemented yet :)

Comment: @dbvt10 Maybe slow down performance is wrong, but take a look at the caveats from the React Native docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Comment: @J.Hesters yep, but remember comparing props is always cheaper than re-render  component :)

Comment: @dbvt10 check this thread https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1667

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no issue in using connect and PureComponent. PureComponent renders if the props have changed and `connect()` maps the redux state to props. See in [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/v322ojjly7) by the redux team. I have replaced the TodoList component with a Purecomponent:

```
class TodoList extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { todos, toggleTodo } = this.props;
    return (
      <ul>
        {todos.map(todo => (
          <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} onClick={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

/*
const TodoList = ({ todos, toggleTodo }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)
*/
```

It works just the same.

Comment: "PureComponent renders if the props have changed..." but only shallowly. It's important to make the distinction.

Comment: True. However, if you use "immutables" in your redux project (which I recommend), chances of a bug like this are very low. In my experience the issue is often the opposite; components render too often because `mapStateToProps` always returns new objects.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! Will use this :)

Answer (score 10):

Actually `connect()` function makes the wrapped component pure by default (see [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#pure-boolean)). That is, the wrapped component will be rerendered only when the properties change (state or own props). So there's no point in inheriting from PureComponent, because `shouldComponentUpdate` logic is already implemented in HOC produced by `connect()`.

> I've heard that PureComponents can slow down performance...

Shallow props comparison performed by PureComponent is relatively cheap operation. I don't think it's going to be an issue.

Comment: You are wrong because HOC doesn't compare component's state, but PureComponent does. So if component has its own state it makes sense to use PureComponent.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with list items that were connected components and ended up here after googling for it.

I will add the description of the problem and my solution here:

The `mapStateToProps` looks something like this

```
import { defaultMemoize } from 'reselect';

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  const createMergedItem = defaultMemoize((item, edit) =>
    edit
      ? { ...item, edit: true }
      : { ...item, edit: false }
  );
  return (state, { item, edits }) => {
    //returning same ref when item and edits[item.id] didn't change
    return createMergedItem(item, Boolean(edits[item.id]));
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(Item);
```

In the List component

```
items.map(item=>(<Item key={item.id} item={item} edit={edit} />)
```

The code is a bit simplified but what it does is that List passes an item and edit to each Item component as props, edit is an object that has members with an item.id as key. If I have an item with id 1 and edits is `{1:anythingTruthy}` then the item 1 is in edit mode.

When I'd change an item in the list from or to edit mode then all the items in the list that weren't in changed would re render even though mapStateToProps would return the same reference as last time.

I always thought that connect would return a pure component but I was mistaken, the solution is to make Item a pure component and with [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html) this is very simple:

```
import { memo } from 'react';
//mapStateToProps is the same
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(memo(Item));//wrap Item in memo
```

Where Item is a functional component (`props=>jsx`).

when you change edit mode of one item in the list the `edit` prop will change for all items but thanks to `defaultMemoize` and returning a function from `mapStateToProps` that crates a memoized `createMergedItem` function it'll return props that has the same reference as the last one. This was not enough because the Item function was still called. I had to also use `React.memo` to make Item a pure component.

Answer (score 0):

Pure component does the shallow comparison of props and re-renders only if props are changes.

connect(HOC) also does the shallow comparison and re-rendering bases on comparison.

**Both do the same job. so there is no harm in using both in same component, but while using both, post connect does the comparison, pure component will also do it's shallow comparison. which is repetitive and can be time taking.**

Avoid using pure component while using connect.